# Unit Test Function 'XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy' is Deprecated in Xcode Beta 5 / Swift 4.0

Tags: swift, unit-testing

The unit test function 'XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy' is deprecated in Xcode beta 5 / Swift 4.0, and I'm just wondering how to use the new equivalent?

Here's my code:

```
XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(try Features.sumValues(x: zEarthAbnormal), 54.800583, accuracy: 0.0001)
```

and this is what the warning says:

> 'XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(*:*:accuracy:*:file:line:)' is deprecated: renamed to 'XCTAssertEqual(*:*:accuracy:*:file:line:)'

Comment: Did you notice that Xcode has a Fix-it for that? Click on the yellow triangle -> "Fix" --> Done.

Comment: For some reason when I clicked it, it delete the whole function name. Maybe I didn't click it properly, but it's nice to know they work the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out, the answer is quite simple. 
Just delete 'WithAccuracy' and the function works just the same.

```
XCTAssertEqual(try Features.sumValues(x: zEarthAbnormal), 54.800583, accuracy: 0.0001)
```